# Alinhamento de div lado a lado

Tags: html, css

Quero por as duas `divs` (verde e vermelha) alinhadas lado a lado como estão, porém a verde deveria ficar fixa alinhada na direita, enquanto a vermelha alinhada a esquerda, então coloquei a `margin-left:0vw;` para a verde, e não resolveu, qual procedimento deveria fazer para deixar fixo a vermelha à esquerda, e a verde à direita?

```css
div.container {
        height: 100%;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #088fad 20%, #00d5ff 100%);
    }

    div.titulo {
        font-size: 5vw;
        background-color: blue;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3vw;
        position: relative;
    }

    div.op1 {
        width: 38%;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: red;
        font-size: 3vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5vw 0vw 5vw 0vw;
        min-width:40vw;
    }

    div.op2 {
        width: 38%;
        background-color: green;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 0vw;
        font-size: 3vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5vw 0vw 5vw 0vw;
        min-width:40vw;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    <div class="titulo">O que você está procurando?</div>
    <div class="op1">Opção 1</div>
    <div class="op2">Oção 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não entendi o que está de errado...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seria isso?
No caso, é só adicionar na `div2` a propriedade `float:right;`, para que a div "flutue" à direita.
Espero ter ajudado!

```css
div.container {
        height: 100%;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #088fad 20%, #00d5ff 100%);
    }

    div.titulo {
        font-size: 5vw;
        background-color: blue;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3vw;
        position: relative;
    }

    div.op1 {
        width: 38%;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: red;
        font-size: 3vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5vw 0vw 5vw 0vw;
        min-width:40vw;
    }

    div.op2 {
        width: 38%;
        background-color: green;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 0vw;
        font-size: 3vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5vw 0vw 5vw 0vw;
        min-width:40vw;
        float:right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    <div class="titulo">O que você está procurando?</div>
    <div class="op1">Opção 1</div>
    <div class="op2">Oção 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa simples e rapida é usar a propriedade space-between das flex-box, exemplo...

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.titulo {
   font-size: 5vw;
        background-color: blue;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3vw;
        position: relative;
}
.ctnFlex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
 div.op1 {
        width: 38%;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: red;
        font-size: 3vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5vw 0vw 5vw 0vw;
        min-width:40vw;
    }

    div.op2 {
        width: 38%;
        background-color: green;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 0vw;
        font-size: 3vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5vw 0vw 5vw 0vw;
        min-width:40vw;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="titulo">O que você está procurando?</div>
    <div class="ctnFlex">
       <div class="op1">Opção 1</div>
       <div class="op2">Oção 2</div>
      
    </div>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

FEITO COM FLOAT

```css
div.container {
        height: 100%;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #088fad 20%, #00d5ff 100%);
    }

    div.titulo {
        font-size: 5vw;
        background-color: blue;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3vw;
        position: relative;
    }

    div.op1 {
        width: 38%;
        float:left;
        background-color: red;
        font-size: 3vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5vw 0vw 5vw 0vw;
        min-width:40vw;
    }

    div.op2 {
        width: 38%;
        background-color: green;
        float:right;
        margin-right: 0vw;
        font-size: 3vw;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5vw 0vw 5vw 0vw;
        min-width:40vw;
        float:right;
    }
    .clean{clear:both;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    <div class="titulo">O que você está procurando?</div>
    <div class="op1">Opção 1</div>
    <div class="op2">Oção 2</div>
    <div class="clean"></div>
</div
```

Comment: Alguns navegadores mobile, como o padrão do android, ainda não suportam viewports units (wm,vh,vmin,vmax...)